# how to close Iframe using paremt post message in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, postmessage

I have a simple block which contains an iframe, I would like a user to be able to close the iframe using a button.

Here is what I have so far

JS

> **UPDATE**

```
  document.querySelector(DOM.videoclosebtn).addEventListener('click', closeIframeContainer);
    var closeIframeContainer =function(){
        window.parent.postMessage("event=closeiframe", "*");
    };

    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessageFromIframe, false);
    function receiveMessageFromIframe(msg) {
        if (event == "closeiframe") {
            document.getElementById('iframe-container').remove();
        }else{
           alert('hehehe');
        }
    }
```

Here is index.html with iframe

```
<div id="iframe-container">

            <iframe src="/videoexplainer/data.html" style="border:none"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Here is data.html

```
 <div id="video-close_btn" class="video-btn">
                    <img src="images/x.png" />
                </div>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'window' of null
    at HTMLDivElement.closeIframeContainer (videoexplainer.js:123)
```

unfortunately its not working, what do I need to do get what I want?

Comment: When asking a question about something that doesn't work, it's helpful to explain exactly what "not working" means: errors in the console? Nothing happens? Wrong thing happens? People cannot always just look at the code you post and immediately understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code assigns the return value from the `.postMessage()` call to `getIFrameID`, but then you expect to use it as a DOM node reference.

```
var closeIframeContainer = function(){
   var getIframeID = document.getElementById('iframe-container');
   getIframeID.parent.postMessage("*");
   getIframeID.style.display="none";
};
```

Get the element node reference first, and then do the other operations.

Comment: I have tested your method I am getting the following error : ~videoexplainer.js:124 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of null`

Comment: @user9964622 well what were you getting from your original code?

Comment: This => Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'window' of null

Comment: OK, well look, you have to *explain* in your question what's going wrong, and also post *all* the relevant code. The code you posted doesn't refer to the symbol `window` at all, so it cannot be the source of the error.

Comment: @user9964622 your `iframe-container` element is a `<div>`, not an `<iframe>`. And the parent window of the `iframe` is just `window` in the context of your event handler.